# Convert html input to erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I convert this:

```
<input type="file" id="file" name="file">
```

To a Rails input, if I can say it that way and if I change it to a Ruby input do I have to change anything in my JS code? Is there any benefits on using the code this way or can I use the html way?

Comment: You mean "Rails input" not "Ruby input".

Comment: Yeah thanks for the correction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
<%= file_field_tag 'file' %>
```

It will generate this HTML

```
<input id="file" name="file" type="file" />
```

More info - [Rails Form Helper file_field_tag](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.2.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-file_field_tag)

You can use it in raw html as well, but when you are using Rails, its recommended to follow the conventions.

Comment: Is there a way, through this code, to manipulate for example the files name? Like print its name in other page, another view to be more especific and keep it there?

Comment: Sorry I couldn't understand you, what do you mean by print it's name in other page?

Comment: Hmmm... I select the file and then in other view I have the "history" of the files I selected

Comment: To get the file name in client side you can use Javascript, take a look at this https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-get-selected-file-name-from-input-type-file-using-jquery.php

Comment: And locally? What I mean is that when I select the file, then, in a view called History for example, I can have access to the name of the file I selected. Locally.

Comment: Yes, in the above example you can do it locally, at the time you select the file.

Comment: And then save it?

Comment: If you want to save file then you can take a look at ActiveStorage in Rails, https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html